# Running Valgrind fails

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm trying to run `valgrind` in order to identify memory leaks in my program.

Unfortunately, running it fails as follows:

```
igor@WaylandGnome ~/dbhandler/Debug/dbhandler $ valgrind --leak-check=full dbhandler
==32622== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32622== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32622== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32622== Command: dbhandler
==32622== 
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x8F 0xEA 0x78 0x10 0xD0 0x8 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x89
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=NONE
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==32622== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x40197cf.
==32622==    at 0x40197CF: get_common_indices.constprop.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x401ACB6: init_cpu_features.constprop.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x401BE1D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x4001FDB: _dl_start (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x4001057: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==32622== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==32622== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==32622==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==32622==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==32622== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==32622==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==32622==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==32622== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==32622== probably kill your program.
==32622== 
==32622== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==32622==  Illegal opcode at address 0x40197CF
==32622==    at 0x40197CF: get_common_indices.constprop.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x401ACB6: init_cpu_features.constprop.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x401BE1D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x4001FDB: _dl_start (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622==    by 0x4001057: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.33.so)
==32622== 
==32622== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32622==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32622==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==32622== 
==32622== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==32622== 
==32622== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==32622== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction
```

Any idea what is happening?

I'm running Gentoo here and my program is built with C++11 standard.

Comment: Can you successfully use valgrind at all? Confirm by running a simple program like hello world through it.

Comment: @user4581301, you are right - looks lie I can't run it at all...

Comment: That's about the worst outcome, unfortunately. Where did you get Valgrind from? If not Portage, nuke what you have as politely as possible and let Portage to the heavy lifting.

Comment: @user4581301, I did install it from Portage..

Comment: Crap. So much for the low-hanging fruit. You're going to need someone who knows the guts of Valgrind a <expletive deleted> of a lot better than me.

Comment: Side note: If Valgrind is out while waiting for patches, see if [leak sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html) is available to you and can get you the info you need.

Comment: Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. (I know this isn't _exactly_ a fix my code question, but most of the same guidance applies)

Answer (score 0):

This is valgrind bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381819

There is a patch attached to the bug but the patch is not in the latest valgrind release as it is reported as not being complete.